# how do i implement google maps infobox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map set up that works fine with the default InfoWindow however I'm looking for something a little more stylized, I would like to be able to control how this window looks. I have looked at the InfoBox examples and docs but am unable to see how I can implement this into my code.

Javascript:

```
// Enable the visual refresh
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

    function initialize() {
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.58448934362705, -2.2128868103027344);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 19,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              draggable: false,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.58448934362705, -2.2128868103027344),
              icon: {
                size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                url: "marker.png"
              }
            });

      });



      setMarkers(map, obstacles);
    }

var obstacles = [
  ['The Start', -2.2128868103027344 ,52.58448934362705, 1, '<b>The Start</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Chatway Chase', -2.2232937812805176,52.585369365082556, 1, '<b>Chatway Chase</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Elephant Fence', -2.2287386655807495,52.585874554601546, 1, '<b>Elephant Fence</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Elephant Fence', -2.2254180908203125,52.586862101811484, 1, '<b>Elephant Fence</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Elephant Fence', -2.2167277336120605,52.58403954805975, 1, '<b>Elephant Fence</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Elephant Fence', -2.216741144657135,52.58465231189634, 1, '<b>Elephant Fence</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Rabbit Hill', -2.220606207847595,52.58593322139412, 1, '<b>Rabbit Hill</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Brasher Disley Steplechase', -2.2237443923950195,52.58636018290797, 1, '<b>Brasher Disley Steplechase</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Bracken Maze Torture', -2.228196859359741,52.58881105708316, 1, '<b>Bracken Maze Torture</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['The Slalom', -2.233647108078003,52.590078809218845, 1, '<b>The Slalom</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Jungle Trench Battlefileds', -2.2293394804000854,52.5877551121424, 1, '<b>Jungle Trench Battlefileds</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Gurkha Grand National', -2.23097562789917,52.58586803606421, 1, '<b>Gurkha Grand National</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Jungle Water Slalom', -2.2270596027374268,52.58515425035844, 1, '<b>Jungle Water Slalom</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg'],
  ['Technospanner Legover', -2.2247743606567383,52.58636670137212, 1, '<b>Technospanner Legover</b>', 'bracken-maze-torture.jpg']  
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {

    var image = {
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      url: "marker.png"
    };

    var makeInfoWindow = function(marker, obs) {

      // Create info window. In content you can pass simple text or html code.
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div style='width:220px; position:relative;'>" + obs[4] + "<img src='" +  + "'/></div>",
        maxWidth: 220,
      });



      var boxText = document.createElement("div");
      boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
      boxText.innerHTML = "City Hall, Sechelt<br>British Columbia<br>Canada";

      var myOptions = {
         content: boxText
         ,disableAutoPan: false
         ,maxWidth: 0
         ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
        ,zIndex: null
        ,boxStyle: { 
            background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
            ,opacity: 0.75
            ,width: "280px"
         }
         ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
         ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
         ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
         ,isHidden: false
         ,pane: "floatPane"
         ,enableEventPropagation: false
      };


      // Add listner for marker. You can add listner for any object. It is just an example in which I am specifying that infowindow will be open on marker mouseover
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    };

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var obstacle = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(obstacle[2], obstacle[1]);
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: obstacle[0],
        zIndex: obstacle[3],
        labelContent: i + 1,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(14, 29),
        labelClass: "labels"
    });
    makeInfoWindow(marker, obstacle);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't understand. Where lies the difficulty?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get it to work i always end up with the last item in the array showing.

Comment: That sounds like a general problem in your code, not about your infobox. Could you set a jsfiddle, or a jsbin??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
    #map-canvas, #map_canvas {
      height: 800px;
    }
    .infobox-wrapper {
    display:none;
    }
    .infobox, .infoBox {
        margin-top: 8px;
        background:#FFF;
        color:#666;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        padding: .5em 1em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0  8px #000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
    }
    .labels {
       color: #FFF;
       font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
       text-align: center;
       width: 26px;
       white-space: nowrap;
       letter-spacing: 0;
     }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    // Enable the visual refresh
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;




var obstacles = [
  ['The Start', -2.2128868103027344 ,52.58448934362705, 1, '<h2>The Start</h2>', 1],
  ['Chatway Chase', -2.2232937812805176,52.585369365082556, 1, '<h2>Chatway Chase</h2>', 2],
  ['Elephant Fence', -2.2287386655807495,52.585874554601546, 1, '<h2>Elephant Fence</h2>', 3],
  ['Elephant Fence', -2.2254180908203125,52.586862101811484, 1, '<h2>Elephant Fence</h2>', 4],
  ['Elephant Fence', -2.2167277336120605,52.58403954805975, 1, '<h2>Elephant Fence</h2>', 5],
  ['Elephant Fence', -2.216741144657135,52.58465231189634, 1, '<h2>Elephant Fence</h2>', 6],
  ['Rabbit Hill', -2.220606207847595,52.58593322139412, 1, '<h2>Rabbit Hill</h2>', 7],
  ['Brasher Disley Steplechase', -2.2237443923950195,52.58636018290797, 1, '<h2>Brasher Disley Steplechase</h2>', 8],
  ['Bracken Maze Torture', -2.228196859359741,52.58881105708316, 1, '<h2>Bracken Maze Torture</h2>', 9],
  ['The Slalom', -2.233647108078003,52.590078809218845, 1, '<h2>The Slalom</h2>', 10],
  ['Jungle Trench Battlefileds', -2.2293394804000854,52.5877551121424, 1, '<h2>Jungle Trench Battlefileds</h2>', 11],
  ['Gurkha Grand National', -2.23097562789917,52.58586803606421, 1, '<h2>Gurkha Grand National</h2>', 12],
  ['Jungle Water Slalom', -2.2270596027374268,52.58515425035844, 1, '<h2>Jungle Water Slalom</h2>', 13],
  ['Technospanner Legover', -2.2247743606567383,52.58636670137212, 1, '<h2>Technospanner Legover</h2>', 14]  
];

    function initialize() {
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.58448934362705, -2.2128868103027344);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 19,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var infobox = new InfoBox({
      map: map,
         disableAutoPan: false,
         maxWidth: 150,
         pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -40),
         zIndex: null,
         alignBottom: true,
         boxStyle: {
            width: "280px"
        },
        closeBoxMargin: "-16px -20px 0px 0px",
        closeBoxURL: "interactive-map-info-close.png",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)

    });

      setMarkers(map, infobox);
    }



function setMarkers(map, infobox) {

  var image = {
    size: new google.maps.Size(38, 38),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(38, 38),
    url: "marker.png"
  };



  for (var i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++) {
    var obstacle = obstacles[i];
    var data = obstacle[0];
    var index = obstacle[5];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(obstacle[2], obstacle[1]);
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: obstacle[0],
        zIndex: obstacle[3],
        labelContent: i + 1,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(13, 33),
        labelClass: "labels"
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, data) {
        return function() {
          infobox.setContent(data);
          infobox.open(map, marker)        
        }
      })(marker, data));
  }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```